# Custom HTML helper class in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've been using custom HTML helper extensions for some time now. Lately I've decided it would be nice to use helper that look like this

```
<%: Style.MyCustomExtensionMethod(...) %>
```

or

```
@Style.MyCustomExtensionMethod("abcd")
```

I searched all over the net but always ran into custom HTML helpers that are called via `Html.`

I also inherited from HtmlHelper class like this

```
public static class Style : HtmlHelper
{
    public static string test(this HtmlHelper helper, string text)
    {
        return text;
    }
}
```

but that didn't work (in the View it says it cannot find method test() that takes one parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve such syntax in your view you could always:

```
public static class Style
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MyCustomExtensionMethod(string foo)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Obviously because you are not extending an `HtmlHelper` you no longer have access to the HttpContext which limits the usefulness of such thing.

Another possibility is to [modify the base class](http://develoq.net/2011/how-to-create-custom-html-helpers-for-asp-net-mvc-3-and-razor-view-engine/) all your razor views are deriving from by extending `WebViewPage` and adding a custom property to which you could write extension methods later. The question you have to ask yourself is: is it worth it?

Personally I find nothing wrong/ugly/incorrect about:

```
@Html.MyCustomExtensionMethod("abcd")
```

or:

```
@Url.MyCustomExtensionMethod("abcd")
```

Those are the de-facto standards in ASP.NET MVC and every developer should be familiar with. It's also easier with Intellisense and discoverability of your custom helpers.

Comment: Making just a simple static class will not be enough because of the reasons you mentioned (lack of HttpContext). It was actually this link in the Comments of the post that you linked to that helped me http://develoq.net/2011/how-to-change-base-type-of-razor-view-engine-pages/

Comment: Html and Url helpers are fine but I would like to have them grouped, for instance CSS helpers in one class, scripts in another and even though I can have that with Html helpers now, I would still like to tell them apart (visually). Thanks

Comment: This post by Phil Haack might be the most complete resource for this kind of extensibility http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx